# How to replace the text with the previous text in the label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a code to have a label, and a button, and whenever we click on the button the defined text just replaces with the previous text in the Label. Right now it adds it the previous text.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

my_label = Label(text="Hello").pack()

def test():
    my_label = Label(text="Bye").pack()

my_button = Button(root, text="Open a file", command=test).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I saw that people using `config` to do that. But I don't understand what is the problem with my code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

global my_label
my_label = Label(text="Hello").pack()

def test():
    my_label.config(text="Bye")


my_button = Button(root, text="Open a file", command=test).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `global` at the global level.  You should remove that.

The PROBLEM is that the `.pack()` method returns None.  Tkinter is a hopelessly antiquated relic of software days gone by, and does not use good object practices.  You need

```
my_label = Label(text="hello")
my_label.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you, I thaught this problem is only with the grid().

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your tkinter code is covered in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/355230) to the question [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) .

As for what you want to know how to do:

While, generally speaking, you can *change* the options of an existing widget by using the universal widget [config()](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html) method, as you're doing.
There's an even better way to do things when you want to change a *value* that one (or more) of them is displaying. In those cases you can refer one or more widgets to a tkinter [`Variable`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and then just update the variable's value and all the widgets referring to it change.

Here's how to do things that way.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP 8 recommends against `import *`.


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

label_text = tk.StringVar(value="Hello")

my_label = tk.Label(textvariable=label_text)
my_label.pack()

def test():
    label_text.set("Bye")

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Open a file", command=test)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```